# Obtener de un fichero y almacenar un string en un diccionario Python

Tags: python, linux

Tengo un script en *Python* que busca y reemplaza un *string* contenido en todos los archivos dentro de un directorio. Ahora necesito que almacene el resto de esa línea en un diccionario.

Es decir, cuando encuentro esta línea:

```
ORIGIN("ab_220_ABBC2x_5_ABBC2x_OriginDestiny: 
1..............................\n");
```

Mi script la convierte en la siguiente, reemplazando el nombre de la función:

```
RESULT("ab_220_ABBC2x_5_ABBC2x_OriginDestiny: 
1..............................\n");
```

Pero ahora necesito almacenar lo siguiente en un diccionario:

> "ab_220_ABBC2x_5_ABBC2x_OriginDestiny:
>   1..............................\n"`

Ejemplo:

```
dictionary = {'valor1': 'ab_220_ABBC2x_5_ABBC2x_OriginDestiny: 
1..............................\n'}
```

Es decir, que saque el contenido que hay entre `( ... );`.

Esto se lee de un directorio que contiene ficheros **.cc** y **.h** donde las líneas que busco son de este estilo:

```
ORIGIN("ab_220_ABBC2x_5_ABBC2x_OriginDestiny: 
1..............................\n");

ORIGIN("ab_220_ABBC2x_: 3..............................\n");
```

Es decir, son archivos de *C++* que tienen una función con un nombre que quiero reemplazar (eso ya lo hago con mi script) pero además quiero guardar lo que recibe esa función, lo que está entre `( ... );`.

El resultado sería que se reemplazará el nombre de la función en el fichero:

```
DESTINY("ab_220_ABBC2x_5_ABBC2x_OriginDestiny: ...1 \n");
DESTINY("ab_220_ABBC2x_: 3" , value);
```

Y almacenará lo que se le pasa a la función en un diccionario, en este caso:

```
dict = { '1' : 'ab_220_ABBC2x_5_ABBC2x_OriginDestiny: ...1' , 
'2': 'ab_220_ABBC2x_: 3" , value' }
```

Mi script:

```
import re
import os
import shutil
import sys

drc = ''
backup = '/path/bk'
pattern = re.compile('ORIGIN')
oldstr = 'ORIGIN'
newstr = 'DESTINY'

if os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
    drc = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
else:
    print("Cannot find directory: " + sys.argv[1])
    exit()

for dirpath, dirname, filename in os.walk(drc): #Obtiene una lista de las rutas.
    for fname in filename:
        path = os.path.join(dirpath, fname) #Une la ruta con el nombre del archivo.

strg = open(path).read() #Abre los archivos para sólo lectura.
if re.search(pattern, strg): #Si encuentra el patrón
    shutil.copy2(path, backup) #Crear una copia de seguridad.
    strg = strg.replace(oldstr, newstr) #Reemplaza.

f = open(path, 'w') #Abre los archivos en modo escritura.
f.write(strg) #Escribe los cambios.
f.close() #Cierra los archivos.
```

Comment: JaviC sería de gran ayuda que aportaras unas cuantas líneas del archivo original en crudo para poder emular el código. Por otro lado, ¿quieres crear **un diccionario por cada función** que contenga los argumentos de esa función o un **diccionario general** en el que cada clave haga referencia a una funcion y su valor sus argumentos? Un ejemplo con 3  o 4 lineas representativas del txt y con el diccionario diccionarios de salida que esperarias de esas lineas sería de mucha ayuda. La pregunta se cerró originalmente por estar en ingés, eso ya está solventado, he iniciado su reapertura. Saludos.

Comment: Hola FJSevilla, gracias por contestar, ya he editado la pregunta para que se entienda mucho mejor, el caso es que a parte de lo que ya hace mi script que es renombrar la función, quiero almacenar el contenido de lo que se le pasa a esa funcion en un diccionario.

Comment: vale, creo que mas o menos lo entiendo. Con regex usando los parentesis como limitadores no debe entrañar demasiado problema. Incluso puedes separar los parámetros y crear una tupla con los parámetros si te fuera útil: `dict = { '1' :  ('ab_220_ABBC2x_5_ABBC2x_OriginDestiny: ...1') , 
'2': ( 'ab_220_ABBC2x_: 3" ,  'value' )}`. A ver si se reabre y te puedo dar alguna idea.

Comment: Exacto, es lo que quiero hacer, pero no se cómo hacerlo, ya que la forma que tengo de encontrar mi patron bajo un directorio y sustituirlo por el otro nombre "DESTINY" no trabaja con el fichero línea a línea. Por lo que la solución puede ser recorrer otra vez el directorio entero e ir encontrando la palabra "DESTINY" y ahí coger el resto de valores que necesito para el diccionario. Pero no se como hacer esto

Answer (score 0):

Tengo un código que pues lo hace fácilmente, espero sea lo que necesitas.

```
def __init__()
    self.DIC_CMD = self.crearDicCmds()
    self.CMD_U = self.cargarComandos()
    self.DESC_U = self.cargarDescripciones()

def cargarDescripciones(self):
    cmds = list(open('Ficheros/descripciones.txt','r'))
    cmds = [c.strip() for c in cmds]
    return cmds

def cargarComandos(self):
    descs = list(open('Ficheros/comandos.txt','r'))
    descs = [d.strip() for d in descs]
    return descs
#Esto creo que es lo que te sirve
def crearDicCmds(self):
    dic_aux = {}
    for i in range(0, len(self.CMD_U)):
        dic_aux[self.CMD_U[i]] = self.DESC_U[i]
    return dic_aux
```

Comment: No es exactamente lo que quiero, necesito que lea del fichero donde hace el reemplazo en el nombre de la función, lea los parámetros de esa función por ejemplo ("blablabla", valor); y me almacene lo que está entre paréntesis en un diccionario o en otro fichero nuevo

Comment: Bueno, creo que podrías comenzar en colocar la descripción del problema en español, ahorita pueden llegar y llamarte la atención por ello, ya que están luchando porque acá sea totalmente en español. Y por lo que creo entender de tu descripción es que quieres tomar cada linea del fichero como clave-valor, es decir hacer un split() desde el comienzo hasta los dos puntos para que sea tu valor, sin embargo muestras un '100' como clave, que significa ese '100'?

Comment: Acabo de arreglarlo, a ver si se entiende ahora mejor, gracias Victor